# How to work with negative summations?

Tags: number-theory, notation

I was playing with some equations earlier and I found that I could iterate one into itself and it did some cool things.

In these equations I knew this: $W_{n+1} = 1$

Then I found: $W_{n+2} = 3 + 2^{P_n}$

Then this: $W_{n+3} = 3^2 + 3^1 2^{P_n} + 3^0 2^{P_n + P_{n+1}}$

Then this: $W_{n+4} = 3^3 + 3^2 2^{P_n} + 3^1 2^{P_n + P_{n+1}} + 3^0 2^{P_n + P_{n+1} + P_{n+2}}$

And at this point I wanted to generalize this pattern.

This is what I came up with: $W_{n+m} = 3^{m-1} + 3^{m-2}2^{P_n} + 3^{m-3}2^{P_n + P_{n+1}} + ... + 3^2 2^{\sum_{i=0}^{m-4}P_{n+i}} + 3^1 2^{\sum_{j=0}^{m-3}P_{n+j}} + 3^0 2^{\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}P_{n+k}}$

This is cool and seems to fit the pattern, but now if I go back and plug in $m = 1$, then I get

$$W_{n+1} = 1 = 3^{1-1} + 3^{1-2}2^{P_n} + 3^{1-3}2^{P_n + P_{n+1}} + ... + 3^2 2^{\sum_{i=0}^{1-4}P_{n+i}} + 3^1 2^{\sum_{j=0}^{1-3}P_{n+j}} + 3^0 2^{\sum_{k=0}^{1-2}P_{n+k}}$$

Which simplifies to

$$1 = 1 + 3^{-1} 2^{P_n} + 3^{-2} 2^{P_n + P_{n+1}} + ... + 3^2 2^{\sum_{i=0}^{-3} P_{n+i}} + 3^1 2^{\sum_{j=0}^{-2} P_{n+j}} + 3^0 2^{\sum_{k=0}^{-1}P_{n+k}}$$

Which further simplifies to

$$0 = \frac{2^{P_n}}{3} + \frac{2^{P_n + P_{n+1}}}{3^2} + ... + 3^2 2^{\sum_{i=0}^{-3} P_{n+i}} + 3^1 2^{\sum_{j=0}^{-2} P_{n+j}} + 3^0 2^{\sum_{k=0}^{-1}P_{n+k}}$$

This is really cool but I'm more than a touch lost at this point. Do I accept this as a mathematical truth? Or more likely, I screwed up, but where? Frankly, I don't know that plugging in any number for m will actually give a usable result. But I don't think I should be getting negative numbers in a summation. Perhaps I can't use summations like this? It does seem to have a cool wrap-around effect from negative infinity to positive infinity with the 3s.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Who says you can't sum negative numbers?

Comment: Well I mean, that would be like 0<i<-3 which doesn't make sense I think, but I owuldn't know how to sum it and searching for how didn't seem to give me a good answer on what to do.

Comment: So you want to sum over ${i : -3 < i < 0}$. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Can you just change summations like that?

Comment: Your indices of summation need not be positive.

Comment: For flavor, an extremely common object in complex analysis is a *Laurent series*, which not only sums over negative numbers, but infinitely many! Indeed, we can define a Laurent series representation of $f$: $$f(z) = \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} a_j (z-b)^j$$ which converges on an annulus.

Comment: As an aside, if I substitute $n=7$ into $W_{n+1}$ to get $``W_8"$, I'd expect to get the same answer as $n=6$ in $W_{n+2}$. But, assuming that $P_6$ is a real number (or a real valued function/polynomial), they can't be the same. I would recommend changing your notation from $W_{n+m}$ to $W_{n,m}$ or similar, to both help you avoid making mistakes and to minimize confusion for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate things going on here:

1. What happens with a summation whose upper limit is lower than the lower limit?
2. How do I generalize a summation pattern like this in a way that still gets the right answers in the original basic cases?

## 1. "Negative Summations"

${\displaystyle \sum_{i=a}^{b}} f(i)$ generally means something like "the sum of everything in $\{f(i)\mid a\le i\le b\}$". So something like ${\displaystyle \sum_{i=5}^{4}} f(i)$ would be the sum of the elements of $\{f(i)\mid 5\le i\le 4\}=\{f(i)\mid \text{False}\}=\varnothing$. What what is the sum of the empty set? Well, it's useful for a lot of patterns to follow the convention that the "[empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)" is $0$. So all of these "negative summations" would conventionally give $0$.

## 2. A General Formula

But that would seem to give you incorrect expressions since it looks like $W_{n+1}$ would be a sum of positive terms including the term $3^1 2^{\sum_{j=0}^{-2} P_{n+j}}=3>1$.

Instead, we need to write the pattern a little differently. $``\ldots"$ is a bit vague, so we can solve the problem by using *more* summation notation. Following the convention that the empty sum is $0$, we can use $j$ as the index in the exponent of $2$, and $i$ as the index that tells us how many summands are in the exponent of $2$, to arrive at this formula:
$$W_{n+m}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}3^{m-1-i}*2\texttt{^}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i}P_{n+j-1}\right)$$

Then when $m=1$, we have
\begin{align}W_{n+1}&=\sum_{i=0}^{0}3^{-i}*2\texttt{^}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i}P_{n+j-1}\right)
\\&=3^{-0}*2\texttt{^}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{0}P_{n+j-1}\right)
\\&=3^{-0}*2\texttt{^}\left(0\right)\text{ (empty sum)}
\\&=3^{0}*2^0=1\checkmark\end{align}

As an extra check, when $m=3$, we have
\begin{align}W_{n+3}&=\sum_{i=0}^{2}3^{2-i}*2\texttt{^}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i}P_{n+j-1}\right)
\\&=3^{2-0}*2\texttt{^}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{0}P_{n+j-1}\right)+3^{2-1}*2\texttt{^}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{1}P_{n+j-1}\right)+3^{2-2}*2\texttt{^}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2}P_{n+j-1}\right)
\\&=3^{2}*2\texttt{^}\left(0\right)+3^{1}*2\texttt{^}\left(P_{n}\right)+3^{0}*2\texttt{^}\left(P_{n}+P_{n+1}\right)
\\&=3^2 + 3^1 2^{P_n} + 3^0 2^{P_n + P_{n+1}}\checkmark\end{align}

Comment: If I could give you more than 1 upvote, I would. This not only answers my question but about the next five that I had. And looking at what you've written out, I don't think I'd have been able to arrive here on my own. Thank you so much!